# How to use a css class for a select dropdown on two different pages

Tags: css

I have multiple dropdowns (select boxes) on my website - i want to align the dropdown differently like i want some dropdown should come in center on one page but on another page a different select box will come on the right side

my designer is on holidays so i want to try this on my own will someone help me on this, i am not very good on css definition part but i can play with the existing css

a css has been written like this

```
select 
{
background: #F8F8F8;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
padding: 2px;
}
```

i modified it on a page like this

```
select 
{
background: #F8F8F8;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
padding: 2px;
float:left;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

when i looked the result it was looking good on a page but when i moved on to a inner page the select box shifted to different place

how can i use the css differently on different pages???

thanks

Comment: So you want to use the same stylesheet for different pages, but the select boxes must appear differently, right?

Comment: yes i want to use only one css for all the pages, but the UI of the select dropdown should come differently for all the pages, as for example on one page i am showing the filter options using the select on the right but on a different page i am using the select dropdown differently

Answer (score 0):

The `select` tag is a general tag. Any css styling that you give to a `select` tag will be applied to every single select dropdown on your site (assuming the same stylesheet is used)

If you want to have your select dropdown menus appearing differently, then you need to give them an ID so you can target a specific one.

For example

```
#select1{ 
float:right;
}

#select2{
float:left;
}
```

In this scenario, a select field with the id of `select1` will be floated right, and `select2` will be floated left

Comment: Yes correctly said as the <select> tag is a general one so I am very confused how to use it on different pages, because I don't want to use the inline comments

Answer (score 0):

most likely the float:left causes the harm. But you may give them different styles:

```
<select class="first"></select>
<select class="second"></select>

<style>
.first{
    // some stuff
}
.second{
    // some stuff
}
</style>
```

or give them IDs and define two styles accordingly:

```
<select id="first"></select>
<select id="second"></select>


<style>
#first{
    // some stuff
}
#second{
    // some stuff
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet would be to

> **assign different classes to the `<html>` tag on each page**

Example :

```
<html class="page1">
  <head>
     ....
  </head>

  <body>
     ....
     <select>
     ....
     </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

if you have pages like 'page1.html', 'page2.html', etc..., then do something like this...

```
select{
background: #F8F8F8;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
padding: 2px;
}

.page1 select{
float:left;
margin-left:20px;
}

.page2 select{
float:left;
margin-left:40px;
background: blue;
}
```

In this way you can put all the common styles in a single group and the individual styles in a group meant for its own. Hope this helps.